# Android Swipe Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-pageradapter

I'm trying to make a navigation in my app and I can't understand how to implement the navigation tabs in my app.
I've been following [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

As a beginner I couldn't understand how to use the FragmentStatePagerAdapter and where to place it, inside the MainAcitvity or as a new activity.

I searched more guides in google but all I found was depraces or irrelevant.

I need your help to simplify the way to implement navigation tabs in the app.

Comment: Note that the linked solution is a bit outdated. Consider using ViewPager with the [Toolbar](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) and the new TabLayout available in the [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Answer (score 0):

You create the adapter in the FragmentActivity, and attach it to the `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` is a part of the layout, which should be kept in XML code. See `CollectionDemoActivity` in the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

This is from my project, take the code and implement it:

```
public class KataloziSlike extends AppCompatActivity {


    private AdapterCustomPage mAdapterCustomPage;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TextView tv, brojStranica;
    private ImageButton settings, share, locirajMe, back, next, previous;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_katalozi_slike);
        if (Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() == 1) {
            Message.message(KataloziSlike.this, "Katalog ima samo jednu stranu");
        }
        brojStranica = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrojStranicaKataloga);
        brojStranica.setText(String.valueOf(1) + "/" + String.valueOf(Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() + 1));

        mAdapterCustomPage = new AdapterCustomPage(getFragmentManager(), this);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pagerZaSlikeKataloga);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapterCustomPage);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);


        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonKataloziNext);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pozicija = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (pozicija < mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount()) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pozicija + 1);
                }
            }
        });

        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonKataloziPrevious);
        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pozicija = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (pozicija > 0) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pozicija - 1);
                }
            }
        });


        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            previous.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    previous.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    previous.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                if (position == Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size()) {
                    next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                if (Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() != 1) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        Message.message(KataloziSlike.this, "Na prvoj stranici kataloga ste");
                    } else if (position == Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() - 1) {
                        Message.message(KataloziSlike.this, "Na poslednjoj stranici kataloga ste");
                    }
                }

                if (position <= Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() - 1) {
                    YourFragmentInterface fragment = (YourFragmentInterface) mAdapterCustomPage.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position);
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        fragment.fragmentBecameVisible();
                    }
                }

                brojStranica.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() + 1));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
}}
```

Adapter class:

```
package aik.akcijeikatalozi.adapteri;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import aik.akcijeikatalozi.fragments.ImageFragmentKatalozi;
import aik.akcijeikatalozi.fragments.ImageFragmentMapKatalozi;
import aik.akcijeikatalozi.objetki.Katalozi;
import aik.akcijeikatalozi.utils.Message;
import aik.akcijeikatalozi.utils.Static;
/**
 * Created by Vukasin on 7/11/2015.
 */
public class AdapterCustomPage extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    protected Context mContext;
    int maxBrojStrana = Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size();
    int pozicija;
    private ArrayList<Katalozi> mKatalozi;

    public AdapterCustomPage(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }




    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // Create fragment object
        if (position == maxBrojStrana) {
            Fragment fragment = new ImageFragmentMapKatalozi();
            return fragment;
        } else {
            Fragment fragment = new ImageFragmentKatalozi();
            fragment.onPause();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            Log.i("Poizicija", String.valueOf(position));
            String url = Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().get(position);
            args.putString("url", url);

            fragment.setArguments(args);


            String link = Static.katalozi.getUrl();
            args.putString("linkKataloga", link);




            return fragment;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        pozicija = super.getItemPosition(object);
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return maxBrojStrana + 1;
    }

}
```

fragment class:

```
public class ImageFragmentKatalozi extends Fragment implements KataloziSlike.YourFragmentInterface {


    private PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bundle args;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_katalozi_slike, container, false);

        args = getArguments();
        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAdapterZaListanjeKataloga);


        Callback imageLoadedCallback = new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (mAttacher != null) {
                    mAttacher.update();
                } else {
                    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(args.getString("url")).placeholder(R.drawable.load).error(R.drawable.error).into(imageView, imageLoadedCallback);
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.zaProveru);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "sadsadasd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }


    @Override
    public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
        mAttacher.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a full example look this.  https://github.com/erikcaffrey/AndroidDesignSupportLibrary I hope it help you!

Comment: within this project is implemented navigation tabs TabLayout, ViewPager, Fragments @TheUnreal !

Comment: Look this file!  https://github.com/erikcaffrey/AndroidDesignSupportLibrary/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/androititlan/gdg/android_design_support_library/app/ui/fragment/FragmentThree.java  @TheUnreal.

Comment: start from the basics.

Comment: Check this out for beginners. 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout   I hope it helps!! , I do not understand what you want nobody will do your work for you, sometimes one has to learn to understand good Luck!  @TheUnreal

Comment: Where do you place the page content?